# Use STR_TO_DATE in sql with year change

Tags: sql, date, str-to-date

I have this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM giorni WHERE punto = '$punto' && STR_TO_DATE(giorno, '%d/%m/%Y') ...
```

I need to do a similar query for the previous year. How can i do `%Y-1`?

Comment: use `INTERVAL 1 YEAR` from the date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply subtract 1 year from the converted date:

```
... STR_TO_DATE(giorno, '%d/%m/%Y') - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

Comment: Thanks, man!!
So i did like this
$sqlannoprima = "SELECT * FROM giorni WHERE punto = '$punto' && STR_TO_DATE(giorno, '%d/%m/%Y')- INTERVAL 1 YEAR BETWEEN   STR_TO_DATE('" . $d1 . "', '%d/%m/%Y') - interval 1 YEAR AND STR_TO_DATE('" . $d2 . "', '%d/%m/%Y')- interval 1 YEAR ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(giorno, '%d/%m/%Y')- interval 1 YEAR";

Comment: To be honest, if I knew that the dates were coming from PHP I would simply add/subtract/format them using PHP (`DateTime` class).

Comment: It is possibile to add/subtract with INTERVAL a variable, like 
"- INTERVAL $variable YEAR" ? Thanks

Comment: Variable coming from PHP? Yes.